# Ubuntu WiFi is slow after upgrade

Tags: wireless, upgrade, updates

After my latest Ubuntu distro upgrade to version 11.10, wireless connection became extremely slow. The upgrading procedure failed on configuration files update dialog and I rebooted the laptop and run apt-get upgrade... Could that be because of misconfiguration or wrong driver? Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79721/wifi-connection-slow-after-upgrade-to-11-10/108680#108680

Answer (score 1):

You might have several misconfigurations since you mentioned that the upgrading procedure failed. What I suggest is to do a clean install to be on the safe side. Do a backup of your files and just do a clean Ubuntu install. It will save you all the hassle for looking for the culprit and enjoy the 11.10 as new.